# How to get the maximum and minimum salary of all the departments along with department name,manager id, manager name of each department?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
    departments.department_id,
    department_name,
    departments.manager_id,
    first_name,
    max(salary) as Maximum_Salary,
    min(salary) Minimum_Salary 
FROM departments,employees 
WHERE departments.department_id = employees.department_id
    AND departments.manager_id = employee_id 
GROUP BY departments.department_id, department_name, 
    departments.manager_id, first_name
ORDER BY department_id;

SELECT
    departments.department_id,
    department_name,
    departments.manager_id,
    max(salary) as Maximum_Salary,
    min(salary) Minimum_Salary 
FROM departments,employees 
WHERE departments.department_id = employees.department_id 
GROUP BY departments.department_id, department_name, departments.manager_id
ORDER BY department_id;
```

I have tried two queries. I am getting manager's salary every time instead of Maximum and Minimum Salary of the department, but if I remove 'first_name' from the 1st query and modify the joining clause, then the answer is right (i.e. 2nd Query), but I want to get the name of the manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make two JOINs to the employees table : first join between employee and manager_id, and second join between employee and department_id.

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT 
    d.department_id,
    d.department_name,
    d.manager_id,
    m.first_name,
    max(e.salary) as Maximum_Salary,
    min(e.salary) Minimum_Salary
FROM departments d
LEFT JOIN employees e ON d.department_id=e.department_id
LEFT JOIN employees m ON d.manager_id = m.employee_id
GROUP BY d.department_id, d.department_name, 
    d.manager_id, m.first_name
ORDER BY d.department_id;
```

Comment: This worked but Left Join is filtering all the departments so I changed it to inner join on department_id and got my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to select the employees table as following: *employees.salary* and *employees.first_name*.

The query will look like this:

```
select departments.department_id,department_name,departments.manager_id,employees.first_name,max(employees.salary) as Maximum_Salary,min(employees.salary) Minimum_Salary from departments,employees where departments.department_id=employees.department_id and departments.manager_id=employee_id group by departments.department_id,department_name,departments.manager_id,first_name order by department_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Outer Apply to get the min and max salaries by department id and apply that to the manager information.

```
SELECT  d.department_id,
        d.department_name,
        d.manager_id,
        m.first_name,
        s.Maximum_Salary,
        s.Minimum_Salary
FROM    departments d
        INNER JOIN employees m ON m.employee_id = d.manager_id
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT MAX(salary) Maximum_Salary,
                            MIN(salary) Minimum_Salary
                     FROM   employees e
                     WHERE  e.department_id = d.department_id
        ) s
ORDER BY d.department_id
```

if your dbms does not support Outer Apply.. left join will also work

```
SELECT  d.department_id,
        d.department_name,
        d.manager_id,
        m.first_name,
        s.Maximum_Salary,
        s.Minimum_Salary
FROM    departments d
        INNER JOIN employees m ON m.employee_id = d.manager_id
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT   e.department_id,
                            MAX(salary) Maximum_Salary,
                            MIN(salary) Minimum_Salary
                   FROM     employees e
                   GROUP BY e.department_id
                  ) s ON s.department_id = d.department_id
ORDER BY d.department_id
```

Comment: Outer Apply is giving error in my Oracle 11g, but the 2nd one is working fine. Thanks anyway.